# How to delete row of table with a button inside

Tags: php, html

I have a table generated with The foreach construct, on each `<tr>` there is a delete button inside. I want to delete the row containing the button (by the ID) but all I've done is delete the last row (the last ID) that was saved and not the desired.

This is a part of my HTML code:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">
    <table class="Pizarra" id="pizarra" cellspacing="0px";>
        <tr class="trThDos">  
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
            <!-- Comienza PHP -->
            <?php 

            $i = 0;
            foreach ($resultados as $fila)
            {
            ?>

            <tr>

                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $fila['ID']; ?>" />
                <td class="tdTurno"><?php echo '#' . ++$i ?></td>
                <td class="tdImg">
                <?php echo $fila ['value']; 

                switch ($fila['value'])
                {
                    case "0":
                        echo "<img src='./img/consulta-56-2.png'";
                    break;

                    case "1":
                        echo "<img src='./img/shot-56-2.png'";
                    break;

                    case "2":
                        echo "<img src='./img/ta-56-2.png'";
                    break;

                    case "3":
                        echo "<img src='./img/cert-56-2.png'";
                    break;

                    default:
                        echo "Hubo un error en la selección";
                    break;

                } ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                <?php echo $fila ['nombre']; ?>
                </td>
                <td class="tdHr">
                <?php echo $fila ['hora']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="submit" class="btnBorrar" name="btnBorrar" value="X">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?> 
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
// ----------- CONEXIÓN ------------------
try {
    $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=farmacia', 'Emm', ' ');
    $conexion->exec("set names utf8");
    //echo "Conexión OK <br />";

}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
// ----------- TERMINA CONEXIÓN -----------------

if(isset($_POST['btnBorrar'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $statement = $conexion->prepare("DELETE FROM eventos WHERE ID = $id");
    $statement->execute();
    //fetchAll' es clave para que invoque (llame) TODOS los elementos
    $resultados = $statement->fetchAll();

    header("Location:index.php");

    $conexion = null;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GET` method instead of `POST`

In your HTML instead of using submit button use link as shown in below

```
<a href="your\php\file\path\delete.php?id=<?php echo $fila['ID']; ?>">X</a>
```

In the delete.php do like following

```
<?php 
   if(isset($_GET['id'])){
     //get the id into php variable like below
     $id = $_GET['id'];

     //sql query to delete with id variable in where clause

   }
?>
```

Hope this work!!!

Comment: Man!! Thank you! It works. Instead of using an <a> I used a button and 'onclick="location.href=' . I appreciate your time. Also others.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `POST` method, use `GET` and give your delete button a link like

```
yourscript.php?delete={ID}
```

and handle your id like

```
$deleteId = (int)$_GET["delete"];
```

and

```
if(isset($deleteId)){
   //do delete stuff
   $statement = $conexion->prepare("DELETE FROM eventos WHERE ID = $deleteId");
   $statement->execute();
   //fetchAll' es clave para que invoque (llame) TODOS los elementos
   $resultados = $statement->fetchAll();

}
```

---

Replace your hidden input field with this;

```
<a href="yourscript.php?delete=<?php echo $fila['ID']; ?>">Delete me</>
```

Comment: Hi, hakkikonu. I don't know how to link the button. What metod you use?

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code..

**HTML**

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">
        <table class="Pizarra" id="pizarra" cellspacing="0px";>
            <tr class="trThDos">  
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tbody>
            <!-- Comienza PHP -->
            <?php 

            $i = 0;
            foreach ($resultados as $fila) {
            ?>
                <tr id="row_id_<?php echo $fila['ID']; ?>">
                <td class="tdTurno"><?php echo '#' . ++$i ?></td>
                <td class="tdImg"><?php echo $fila ['value']; 

                        switch ($fila['value']){

                        case "0":
                        echo "<img src='./img/consulta-56-2.png'";
                        break;

                        case "1":
                        echo "<img src='./img/shot-56-2.png'";
                        break;

                        case "2":
                        echo "<img src='./img/ta-56-2.png'";
                        break;

                        case "3":
                        echo "<img src='./img/cert-56-2.png'";
                        break;

                        default:
                        echo "Hubo un error en la selección";
                        break;

                        } ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila ['nombre']; ?></td>
                <td class="tdHr"><?php echo $fila ['hora']; ?></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="btnBorrar" name="btnBorrar" value="X" onClick="delete_row(<?php echo $fila['ID']; ?>)"></td>

                </tr>

            <?php } ?> 
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function delete_row(delete_id) {
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'delete_row.php',
            data: 'delete_id='+delete_id,
            success: function(data_respones){
                    $("#row_id_"+delete_id).remove();
            }
         });

}
```

**delete_row.php**

```
<?php
    // ----------- CONEXIÓN ------------------
    try {
        $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=farmacia', 'Emm', ' ');
        $conexion->exec("set names utf8");
    //echo "Conexión OK <br />";

    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        die();
   }


    if(isset($_POST["delete_id"])){
       //do delete stuff
       $statement = $conexion->prepare("DELETE FROM eventos WHERE ID = $id");
       $statement->execute();
    }

?>
```

Comment: Hi, dude. It doesn't works. It seemed an excellent choice. Thanks a lot for your time!